# Flutter 3.3.4 - The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I just upgraded to `Flutter 3.3.4` and now get this error:

```
Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
                                            : file.data()!['photo'];
```

Code looks like this:

```
Future<String?> getUsersPhoto(String uid) async {

    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('users/$uid');
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await reference.get();
    var result = doc.data()!['photo'];

    return result;
}
```

[image]

And a more complex function like this:

```
 Stream<T> findUser<T> ({required String uid, required T builder(Map<String, dynamic>? data, String documentID)}) {
    final ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('users/$uid');
    final Stream<DocumentSnapshot> snapshots = ref.snapshots();

    return snapshots.map((snapshot) => builder(snapshot.data(), snapshot.id));
  }
```

[image]

Any idea how to progress from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert doc.data() to as Map<String, dynamic>.

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
return data['photo']
```